# Nuxt 3 website integrate with Decap CMS with nuxt content. Cms content not showing after deploy website through netlify

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, nuxtjs3, nuxt-content, decap-cms

Hello guys I need some help with nuxt content and Decap CMS work together on live.I have tried to set my file nuxt.config.ts file to target 'static". It still doesn't work.
Here is my yaml setup for my project

```
backend:
  name: github
  repo: wen00033/nuxt-app # Path to your GitHub repository
  branch: master
  base_url: https://selling-site.netlify.app

publish_mode: editorial_workflow
media_folder: content/img
public_folder: content/public
site_url: https://selling-site.netlify.app
```

Here is my config file:

```
export default defineNuxtConfig({
  target: "static",
  buildModules: ["@nuxt/content"],
  devtools: { enabled: true },
  modules: ["@vueuse/nuxt", "@nuxt/ui", "@nuxt/content"],
  colorMode: {
    preference: "light",
  },
});
```

Local site:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SIoTa.png)
Deploy site:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/edz8k.png)

The admin for cms and add content doesn't have any issue.Only the content I couldn't let it output in website.
Here is my repo for further detail: https://github.com/wen00033/nuxt-app

Thank you!

https://github.com/wen00033/nuxt-app

set my file nuxt.config.ts file to target, clean cache

Comment: Did you add your secrets file? Any errors on the production website in the console? Try to build locally too.

Comment: @kissu I tried npm run generate my project, It works normally both Local and Network.